# Drupal CCK - Unlimited fieldsets

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-modules

In Drupal CCK it is possible to set the Number of Values to 'Unlimited,' so that the user can click 'Add Another' and a new field will pop up.

Is this somehow possible with a group of CCK fields as well?  I need to have a textbox and dropdown linked together, and have my users be able to add an unlimited amount to the content-type.  I've seen threads about people working on their own implementation, but have yet to see anything be released on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flexifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexifield) module, some more details about it (from its project page):

> CCK on Drupal 6 is awesome. You can create multi-valued fields, and re-order the field items with drag-and-drop. However, each item in the field is constrained to be of the same type (e.g., text, date, etc.), and creating a new type requires coding by a developer.
>
> Flexifield tries to get around both limitations by letting you create combinations of fields and then use that combination as items within a larger field. You define a field combination by creating a node type and adding fields to it. On a different node type, you can add a flexifield, and then on its configuration form, specify which node types to use as items within the field.

Also see there some links to other modules like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with the CCK 3.x experimental development version. This isn't really recommended, but for more information on the state of multigroup in CCK, check this post out: http://drupal.org/node/494100.

A more recommended alternative for now would be to roll your own compound field module specifically for your needs. I have had success in doing this and got the idea and inspiration from this article: http://www.poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module.